# Execute code after view update in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I want to perform a task (scrolling to bottom, since new elements where added) *after* a view has been updated by vue.

Here is my code:

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.connect();
    },
    connection: null,
    methods: {
        connect: function () {
            ...
        },
        onMessage: function (msg) {

            this.messages.push(msg);
            this.scrollDown();

            return true;
        }, 
        scrollDown: function () {
            $("html, body").animate({
                'scrollTop': $(this).offset().top
            }, 100);
        }
```

As you can see, the `this.scrollDown();` is invoked after `this.messages.push(msg);`, so since the view is not updated immediately the scroll is not well performed. 
How is it supposed to be made?

Comment: It sounds like you want to perform this in the [updated](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try waiting for the DOM to be updated using:

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
  this.scrollDown();
});
```